# Bayesian network calculation

Tags: statistics, probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I have a bayesian network like this:

[image]

The associated probabilities are:
[image]

Now I want to calculate `Pr(Fire =T|Tampering = F, Alarm = T)`.
Using Netica, the value is 1. But how can I manually calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

The probability that `Alarm=True` given `Tampering=False and Fire=False` is found from your table by looking at the cells where the conditions are met; these are the two lower-left cells with probability 0.99 and 0 respectively. Given that one of these outcomes must occur, it is clear that it has to be the one with `Fire=True`, so the probability of this outcome is 1, given the conditions.

If we were to calculate the probabilities, we would say that `pr(Tampering=F, Fire=T | Tampering=F, Alarm=T) = 0.99 / (0.99 + 0) = 1` and `pr(Tampering=F, Fire=T | Tampering=F, Alarm=T) = 0 / (0.99 + 0) = 0`.